# Find all subtrees of size N in an undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graph, tree, graph-theory

Given an undirected graph, I want to generate all subgraphs which are trees of size N, where *size* refers to the number of edges in the tree.

I am aware that there are a lot of them (exponentially many at least for graphs with constant connectivity) - but that's fine, as I believe the number of nodes and edges makes this tractable for at least smallish values of N (say 10 or less).

The algorithm should be memory-efficient - that is, it shouldn't need to have all graphs or some large subset of them in memory at once, since this is likely to exceed available memory even for relatively small graphs.  So something like DFS is desirable.

Here's what I'm thinking, in pseudo-code, given the starting graph `graph` and desired length `N`:

Pick any arbitrary node, `root` as a starting point and call `alltrees(graph, N, root)`

```
alltrees(graph, N, root)
 given that node root has degree M, find all M-tuples with integer, non-negative values whose values sum to N (for example, for 3 children and N=2, you have (0,0,2), (0,2,0), (2,0,0), (0,1,1), (1,0,1), (1,1,0), I think)
 for each tuple (X1, X2, ... XM) above
   create a subgraph "current" initially empty
   for each integer Xi in X1...XM (the current tuple)
    if Xi is nonzero
     add edge i incident on root to the current tree
     add alltrees(graph with root removed, N-1, node adjacent to root along edge i)
   add the current tree to the set of all trees
 return the set of all trees
```

This finds only trees containing the chosen initial root, so now remove this node and call alltrees(graph with root removed, N, new arbitrarily chosen root), and repeat until the size of the remaining graph < N (since no trees of the required size will exist).

I forgot also that each visited node (each root for some call of alltrees) needs to be marked, and the set of children considered above should only be the adjacent unmarked children.  I guess we need to account for the case where no unmarked children exist, yet depth > 0, this means that this "branch" failed to reach the required depth, and cannot form part of the solution set (so the whole inner loop associated with that tuple can be aborted).

So will this work?  Any major flaws?  Any simpler/known/canonical way to do this?

One issue with the algorithm outlined above is that it doesn't satisfy the memory-efficient requirement, as the recursion will hold large sets of trees in memory.

Comment: You say you don't want to have to hold all graphs in memory.  But what about all graphs of size N in memory?

Comment: Just to make sure your terminology is understood, are the following statements true?  2 connected vertices form a graph of size 1.  3 vertices connected in a triangle form a graph of size 3, have 3 subgraphs of size 1, and have 3 subgraphs of size 2.  Right?

Comment: I don't want to hold all graphs of size N in memory either.  Since the branching factor (average node degree) is high, the number of graphs of size N is much larger than the number of graphs of all sizes less than N, so the statements are more or less equivalent anyway.

Comment: Yes, your description of the number of subtrees is correct.  The latter case also has 0 subgraphs of size 3, since cycles are not allowed.

Comment: Are you saying that each node only has an indicator of it's hierachy level? That is, each node knows that it is a grandparent but doesn't know who its children and grandchildren are? Therefore you are saying "If Node is a grandparent, what is the entire possible sample-space of descendants?"

Comment: Alternatively, are you asking for the complete sample space of paths given an edge count?

Comment: You should mention that the graph is acyclic in the question.  Probably in the title.  That makes that answer much easier because in an acyclic graph, once you pick a root, you can treat it as a directed tree.

Comment: Matthew, I'm not sure what you mean by children/parents, etc here.  There is no hierarchy here.  This is a basic undirected graph, with nothing to distinguish the nodes other than arbitrary labels.

Comment: JCooper, the graph is most definitely not acyclic, it has many cycles of different lengths.  Where do you believe I indicated it was acyclic?  I will fix it up if I can.

Comment: @BeeOnRope if the graph is cyclic, undirected then your question doesn't make sense to me. You're looking for the entire sample-space of paths given a maximum edge count? That should have sum(p-choose-(n-m)) m=n->1 graphs

Comment: There is a cyclic graph, and I want all subgraphs which have a given size (by edge count) and are trees.  If you prefer, replace "tree" with "acyclic connected graph".

I didn't really understand your notation, nor do I think the answer could be that simple for an arbitrary graph.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This needs an amount of memory that is proportional to what is required to store the graph.  It will return every subgraph that is a tree of the desired size exactly once.

Keep in mind that I just typed it into here.  There could be bugs.  But the idea is that you walk the nodes one at a time, for each node searching for all trees that include that node, but none of the nodes that were searched previously.  (Because those have already been exhausted.)  That inner search is done recursively by listing edges to nodes in the tree, and for each edge deciding whether or not to include it in your tree.  (If it would make a cycle, or add an exhausted node, then you can't include that edge.)  If you include it your tree then the used nodes grow, and you have new possible edges to add to your search.

To reduce memory use, the edges that are left to look at is manipulated in place by all of the levels of the recursive call rather than the more obvious approach of duplicating that data at each level.  If that list was copied, your total memory usage would get up to the size of the tree times the number of edges in the graph.

```
def find_all_trees(graph, tree_length):
    exhausted_node = set([])
    used_node = set([])
    used_edge = set([])
    current_edge_groups = []

    def finish_all_trees(remaining_length, edge_group, edge_position):
        while edge_group < len(current_edge_groups):
            edges = current_edge_groups[edge_group]
            while edge_position < len(edges):
                edge = edges[edge_position]
                edge_position += 1
                (node1, node2) = nodes(edge)
                if node1 in exhausted_node or node2 in exhausted_node:
                    continue
                node = node1
                if node1 in used_node:
                    if node2 in used_node:
                        continue
                    else:
                        node = node2
                used_node.add(node)
                used_edge.add(edge)
                edge_groups.append(neighbors(graph, node))
                if 1 == remaining_length:
                    yield build_tree(graph, used_node, used_edge)
                else:
                    for tree in finish_all_trees(remaining_length -1
                                                , edge_group, edge_position):
                        yield tree
                edge_groups.pop()
                used_edge.delete(edge)
                used_node.delete(node)
            edge_position = 0
            edge_group += 1

    for node in all_nodes(graph):
        used_node.add(node)
        edge_groups.append(neighbors(graph, node))
        for tree in finish_all_trees(tree_length, 0, 0):
            yield tree
        edge_groups.pop()
        used_node.delete(node)
        exhausted_node.add(node)
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you can destroy the original graph or make a destroyable copy I came up to something that could work but could be utter sadomaso because I did not calculate its O-Ntiness. It probably would work for small subtrees.

- do it in steps, at each step:
- sort the graph nodes so you get a list of nodes sorted by number of adjacent edges ASC
- process all nodes with the same number of edges of the first one
- remove those nodes

For an example for a graph of 6 nodes finding all size 2 subgraphs (sorry for my total lack of artistic expression):

[image]

Well the same would go for a bigger graph, but it should be done in more steps.

Assuming:

- Z number of edges of most ramificated node
- M desired subtree size
- S number of steps
- Ns number of nodes in step
- assuming quicksort for sorting nodes

Worst case:
S*(Ns^2 + M*Ns*Z)

Average case:
S*(NslogNs + M*Ns*(Z/2))

Problem is: cannot calculate the real omicron because the nodes in each step will decrease depending how is the graph...

Solving the whole thing with this approach could be very time consuming on a graph with very connected nodes, however it could be paralelized, and you could do one or two steps, to remove dislocated nodes, extract all subgraphs, and then choose another approach on the remainder, but you would have removed a lot of nodes from the graph so it could decrease the remaining run time...

Unfortunately this approach would benefit the GPU not the CPU, since a LOT of nodes with the same number of edges would go in each step.... and if parallelization is not used this approach is probably bad...

Maybe an inverse would go better with the CPU, sort and proceed with nodes with the maximum number of edges... those will be probably less at start, but you will have more subgraphs to extract from each node...

Another possibility is to calculate the least occuring egde count in the graph and start with nodes that have it, that would alleviate the memory usage and iteration count for extracting subgraphs...

Comment: For a medium-sized highly connected graph the number of possible answers is absurdly large.  Unless you make it easy to iterate through results before you have generated them all, you're going to run out of memory.

Comment: Agree with btilly.  Also, you say "process each node", but don't really elaborate.  In my case, the graph is the "king's graph".  So for example a graph with 16 nodes in a 4x4 grid, with 42 edges.

How do you process all trees of size 15 (for example) efficiently?  I agree that the strategy of deleting nodes when you've finished with them is a good one, but the first iteration is the key one, and you haven't elaborated on it.

Comment: I really thouht that was self descriptive: "process each node" meant "extarct all graphs of size x from that node", while if the first step is too big you can easily divide it in substeps like going with max 10 nodes in each step.

Comment: Marino, nice approach but there is flaw in your approach, it doesn't work with cycled graphs, your approach works in acyclic graphs only. What if there is a cycle in the graph? can you edit your answer with a cyclic graph?

Answer (score 1):

If memory is the biggest problem you can use a NP-ish solution using tools from formal verification. I.e., *guess* a subset of nodes of size N and check whether it's a graph or not. To save space you can use a BDD (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram) to represent the original graph's nodes and edges. Plus you can use a symbolic algorithm to check if the graph you guessed is really a graph - so you don't need to construct the original graph (nor the N-sized graphs) at any point. Your memory consumption should be (in big-O) `log(n)` (where `n` is the size of the original graph) to store the original graph, and another `log(N)` to store every "small graph" you want. 
Another tool (which is supposed to be even better) is to use a SAT solver. I.e., construct a SAT formula that is true iff the sub-graph is a graph and supply it to a SAT solver.

Comment: Memory is a problem, but not in the way you suggest.  It's trival to hold in memory the graph itself (say with ~16 nodes and ~42 edges), but even this graph has at least trillions of subgraphs.  I can't hold trillions of graphs in memory :(

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your solution, but I am not worried about duplicate output. I'm worried about overlapping solutions. If your original graph is a tree then its not a problem, otherwise, say you have a diamond shaped graph with edges (0,1), (0,2),  (1,3), (2,3).

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm reading the question wrong people seem to be overcomplicating it.
This is just "all possible paths within N edges" and you're allowing cycles.
This, for two nodes: A, B and one edge your result would be:
AA, AB, BA, BB

For two nodes, two edges your result would be:
AAA, AAB, ABA, ABB, BAA, BAB, BBA, BBB

I would recurse into a for each and pass in a "template" tuple

```
N=edge count
TempTuple = Tuple_of_N_Items ' (01,02,03,...0n) (Could also be an ordered list!)
ListOfTuple_of_N_Items ' Paths (could also be an ordered list!)
edgeDepth = N

Method (Nodes, edgeDepth, TupleTemplate, ListOfTuples, EdgeTotal)
edgeDepth -=1
For Each Node In Nodes
    if edgeDepth = 0 'Last Edge
        ListOfTuples.Add New Tuple from TupleTemplate + Node ' (x,y,z,...,Node)
    else
        NewTupleTemplate = TupleTemplate + Node ' (x,y,z,Node,...,0n)
        Method(Nodes, edgeDepth, NewTupleTemplate, ListOfTuples, EdgeTotal
next
```

This will create every possible combination of vertices for a given edge count
What's missing is the factory to generate tuples given an edge count.

You end up with a list of possible paths and the operation is Nodes^(N+1)

If you use ordered lists instead of tuples then you don't need to worry about a factory to create the objects.

Comment: Sorry Matthew - I had originally included the word path in my original question, then removed most references (replacing it with tree), but I see I missed a few - I've re-edited it to correct that.

So to clarify, I'm not interested in paths (directed or not), but just the subtrees of the original graph, which are all the _connected, acyclic_ subgraphs of the original of the specified size.

In your example, there would be a single such tree of size 1, containing the A-B edge.  The two edge case for two nodes is not possible since this graph has no multi-edges, so has one edge at most.

Answer (score 0):

For a graph of **K<sub>n</sub>** there are approximately **n!** paths between any two pairs of vertices. I haven't gone through your code but here is what I would do.

1. Select a pair of vertices.
2. Start from a vertex and try to reach the destination vertex recursively (something like dfs but not exactly). I think this would output all the paths between the chosen vertices.
3. You could do the above for all possible pairs of vertices to get all simple paths.

Comment: How would you effectively restrict this to paths of length N?  Also, I don't think this will find all subtrees, it will only find paths between two vertices (for example, it would never produce a path with any vertex degree greater than 2, right?).

So realized my description was wrong, I actually want find all subgraphs which are trees, and not restrict it to paths.

Comment: What does size N mean ? Diameter (longest path) of the tree ?

Comment: Number of edges in the tree, will clarify above also.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the following solution will work.

Go over all partitions into two parts of the set of all vertices. Then count the number of edges which endings lie in different parts (k); these edges correspond to the edge of the tree, they connect subtrees for the first and the second parts. Calculate the answer for both parts recursively (p1, p2). Then the answer for the entire graph can be calculated as sum over all such partitions of k*p1*p2. But all trees will be considered N times: once for each edge. So, the sum must be divided by N to get the answer.

Comment: Note that I don't want to count the trees, but actually generate them.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm is big and not easy one to post here. But here is link to [reservation search](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~avis/doc/rs/implementations/index.html#tre) algorithm using which you can do what you want. [This](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.26.4487&rep=rep1&type=pdf) pdf file contains both algorithms. Also if you understand russian you can take a look to [this](http://shmat-razum.blogspot.com/2008/11/blog-post.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your solution as is doesn't work I think, although it can be made to work. The main problem is that the subproblems may produce overlapping trees so when you take the union of them you don't end up with a tree of size n. You can reject all solutions where there is an overlap, but you may end up doing a lot more work than needed.

Since you are ok with exponential runtime, and potentially writing 2^n trees out, having V.2^V algorithms is not not bad at all. So the simplest way of doing it would be to generate all possible subsets n nodes, and then test each one if it forms a tree. Since testing whether a subset of nodes form a tree can take O(E.V) time, we are potentially talking about V^2.V^n time, unless you have a graph with O(1) degree. This can be improved slightly by enumerating subsets in a way that two successive subsets differ in exactly one node being swapped. In that case, you just have to check if the new node is connected to any of the existing nodes, which can be done in time proportional to number of outgoing edges of new node by keeping a hash table of all existing nodes.

The next question is how do you enumerate all the subsets of a given size
such that no more than one element is swapped between succesive subsets. I'll leave that as an exercise for you to figure out :)

Comment: Can you give a concrete example where my algorithm produces duplicate output?  I can't see it, but it's true there should be a small example.

I don't see how we can examine subsets of N nodes, since N nodes do not defined a graph.  Which edges do you pick, from those which are adjacent to the N nodes?  That is, the statement "these N nodes form a tree" isn't really well formed, since it may be true or false depending on the edges you pick.

Comment: I am not worried about duplicate output. I'm worried about overlapping solutions. If your original graph is a tree then its not a problem, otherwise, say you have a diamond shaped graph with edges (0,1), (0,2),  (1,3), (2,3).  Say you run your subroutine on node 0, with N = 2. Your next level of recursive calls will return trees {(1,3)} and {(2,3)}. When you try to put them together, your don't get a tree since Node 3 is part of two sub trees.

Comment: As for which edges you pick, you pick all the edges from the original graph whose both ends are there in your subgraph. If yo have an adjacency list to begin with, the subgraph can be implicit or you can construct it in O(E +V) time if you have an O(1) time way of looking up which of the nodes are in your subgraph.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a good algorithm (with Perl implementation) at [this site](http://research.nii.ac.jp/~uno/codes.htm) (look for TGE), but if you want to use it commercially you'll need to contact the author.  The algorithm is similar to yours in the question but avoids the recursion explosion by making the procedure include a current working subtree as a parameter (rather than a single node).  That way each edge emanating from the subtree can be selectively included/excluded, and recurse on the expanded tree (with the new edge) and/or reduced graph (without the edge).

This sort of approach is typical of graph enumeration algorithms -- you usually need to keep track of a handful of building blocks that are themselves graphs; if you try to only deal with nodes and edges it becomes intractable.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a graph with with edges e_1, e_2, ..., e_E.

If I understand correctly, you are looking to enumerate all subgraphs which are trees and contain N edges.

A simple solution is to generate each of the E choose N subgraphs and check if they are trees.
Have you considered this approach? Of course if E is too large then this is not viable.

EDIT:

We can also use the fact that a tree is a combination of trees, i.e. that each tree of size N can be "grown" by adding an edge to a tree of size N-1. Let E be the set of edges in the graph. An algorithm could then go something like this.

```
T = E
n = 1
while n<N
    newT = empty set
    for each tree t in T
        for each edge e in E
            if t+e is a tree of size n+1 which is not yet in newT
                add t+e to newT 
    T = newT
    n = n+1
```

At the end of this algorithm, T is the set of all subtrees of size N. If space is an issue, don't keep a full list of the trees, but use a compact representation, for instance implement T as a decision tree using [**ID3**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm).

Comment: This certainly works, but in my case the fraction of trees compared to the number of subgraphs would be vanishingly small (this is probably true of most graphs in general), so this fails the criteria of being O(actual number of graphs)

Comment: Well, to be fair, you did not include that criterion in your question :) You only talk about space complexity.

Answer (score -2):

I think problem is under-specified. You mentioned that graph is undirected and that subgraph you are trying to find is of size N. What is missing is number of edges and whenever trees you are looking for binary or you allowed to have multi-trees. Also - are you interested in mirrored reflections of same tree, or in other words does order in which siblings are listed matters at all?

If single node in a tree you trying to find allowed to have more than 2 siblings which should be allowed given that you don't specify any restriction on initial graph and you mentioned that resulting subgraph should contain all nodes. 
You can enumerate all subgraphs that have form of tree by performing depth-first traversal. You need to repeat traversal of the graph for every sibling during traversal. When you'll need to repeat operation for every node as a root.
Discarding symmetric trees you will end up with

```
 N^(N-2)
```

trees if your graph is fully connected mesh or you need to apply [Kirchhoff's Matrix-tree theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem)

Comment: Hi Alexei,

I'm not sure what you mean by "what is missing is the number of edges".

There is no restriction to binary trees.  The trees I am looking for are the typical ones in a graph-theoretic sense - vertices typically don't have any order in a graph, and neither do they in trees that form a graph.  I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "mirrored reflection", but basically each tree is completely defined by the (unordered) set of edges it contains, and there should be no duplicates.

Comment: About your proposed solution, how to you propose to efficiently "discard symmetric trees"?  These will dominate the enumeration, and cause it to be infeasible in time (to generate and discard the trees) and space (to remember all trees so that discarding is possible) - so that even if the actual number of trees is tractable, this generation strategy won't be.

Comment: if you have a 3 node tree with root A and leafs B and C (A (B, C)) the its mirror will be (A (C, B)) as far as I know.

Comment: I'm using "tree" in [this sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29) - there is no root, nor ordering of any of the nodes.  Basically a "tree" here means a connected, acyclic graph.